# Find query with nested document throws a Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I was trying to get all documents whose `place_id` is equal to `4` using the query below but I'm getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):1:23.
```

Did I type something wrong? The query I'm using is:

```
db.sidebar.find({ result.place_id: 4 });
```

And this is an example document:

```
{  
    "_id":ObjectId("5aebb473e8e191cb74ef8877"),
    "result":{  
        "place_id":4,
        "formatted_address":"589 Doyle Divide",
        "geometry":{  
            "location":{  
                "lat":"-18.8806",
                "lng":"177.1928"
            }
        },
        "international_phone_number":"(571) 978-2039 x11427",
        "name":"Walker Inc",
        "opening_hours":{  
            "weekday_text":[  
                "Monday: 01:00 PM – 03:30 PM",
                "Tuesday: 01:00 PM – 03:30 PM",
                "Wednesday: 01:00 PM – 03:30 PM",
                "Thursday: 01:00 PM – 03:30 PM",
                "Friday: 01:00 PM – 03:30 PM",
                "Saturday: 01:00 PM – 03:30 PM",
                "Sunday: 01:00 PM – 03:30 PM"
            ]
        },
        "url":"https://maps.google.com/?cid=4",
        "website":"http://www.Stracke - Wintheiser.com/"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to access the fields of an embedded document. That means you need to add quotes around those fields:

```
db.sidebar.find({ "result.place_id": 4 });
```

You might think this should also work:

```
db.sidebar.find({ result: { place_id: 4 });
```

But while the former is asking MongoDB to look for a document with a `place_id` field whose value is `4`, inside a field `result` (which might contain other fields as well), the later will look for an exact match of the subdocument, that is, it will match only documents whose `result` field is **exactly** `{ place_id: 4 }`, without any other field in it.